# Error running Tomcat 6.0.43: HTTP Connector node not found: set up one in the server.xml

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I am trying to configure Tomcat in Intellij for a project but I got stuck at this error after trying to run Tomcat. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the server.xml was missing? I just added that and the Connector node and solved my problem. Weird :)

Answer (score 6):

Uncomment/add corresponding `<Connector port=...` node into your *Tomcat/conf/server.xml* file